# Fatch records on the bases of has_and_belongs_to_many association -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Lodging` which has association `has_and_belongs_to_many  :amenities` Now I want a single query which return all `lodgings` which has `amenities` with ids in an array like `[2,1,3]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `joins`.

```
Lodging.joins(:amenities).where(amenities: { id: [2, 1, 3] })
```

It may also be worthwhile to mention that joins, by default, uses an `INNER JOIN`, which means that doing just `Lodging.joins(:amenities)` will exclude all lodgings without an any amenities.

Comment: Thanks @jvnill .This is what i need and I understood. :)